# Let $n\in N, n\geq 2$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n\in N, n\geq 2$.  Which of the following statements are true?

1. Any finite group $G$ of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(R)$
2. The group $Z_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_2(R)$
3. The group $Z_(12)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_7$

My idea is:
1st option I know it is true because G impeds symmetric group and that one impeds Matrix group by permutation matrix.

option 2 I donèt have any idea how the 2 by 2 matrix of entries from Real numbers can be isomorphic to $Z_n$

option 3 I studied one line If G is a group of order n then G is isomorphic to subgroup of $S_n$ source of this line is Dummit and foote algebra book.  By this statement I assure option 3 is also wrong

Any body please guide me and post your thoughts

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

2. What is the order of the matrix representing the rotation of $2\pi/n$?
3. What is the order of $(123)(4567) \in S_7$?

Comment: 3. 12 by this how did you get this subgroup is isomorphic to $Z_12$

Comment: 2. Sorry sir I don't know..can you please explain sir